# Green monsters, one cyborg, the other eyeless

Tags: character-identification

These are figurines that are part of a Sand Tray set that I'm trying to identify. There is no certainly they are from the same continuity. When I Google Image searched them I got a Ghillie suit, and a figurine of a man. Nice work Google Image...

[image]

Has the following writing on it.

> ©2001 SWC Inc, China

Also had a hole in the foot, as if it was attached to a base.

[image]

Comment: The design aesthetic makes me think of Mutant Chronicles, but those are always on a round or hexagonal base as far as I can tell.

Comment: Is there any writing on the rear or bottom?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots The foot of the large one has a hole, as if it was once attached to a base.

Comment: @Valorum ©2001 SWC Inc, China

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The upper one is a Stan Winston Creatures "[Horgg the Dismantler](http://www.toymania.com/columns/spotlight/swhorgg.shtml)" figurine, part of the Mutant Earth line of toys.

> The year is 2099, and the place is a dystopia called Mutant Earth.
>   Mutant Earth is the latest line to be released from Stan Winston
>   Creatures, and the premise is that of an embattled earth five years
>   after a great alien invasion. From the ruins of that invasion,
>   humanity is trying to pick up the pieces and reclaim the planet
>   against impossible odds through Trakk, the heroic leader. Due to the
>   invasion, there are also some mutants about, hence the clever title
>   for the story. The real question you have to ask is why don't all
>   these aliens who want to invade earth watch all our movies that make
>   their way across the void when being broadcast, because if they saw
>   Independence Day, they know they won't win. Then again, if they caught
>   Battlefield Earth, maybe we deserve it!

[image]

[The other item has been incorrectly identified by user Creationedge as a "*spawning* Urak Hai"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/175808/20774) when it is, in fact a [Toy-Biz "**Dungeons of Isengard Newborn** Uruk Hai"](http://smalltraditions.com/toy_biz_lord_of_the_rings_figure_samwise_orc_overs-lot6202.aspx)

[image]

Comment: Not _incorrect_. The play action of the toy is to make it spawn the newborn.

Comment: @CreationEdge - That sounds gross. I pity the weird child who picks that one as his therapy sandbox toy.

Comment: Yeah, I always thought it a weird one, plus it doesn't work very well. The Orc, though, is nice.

Answer (score 15):

The first is a spawning Urak-Hai from a *Lord of the Rings* toy:

[image]
<sup>Click for larger</sup>

I knew this because I own it.

It's based on this scene from film:

[The other item has been identified by user Valorum as a "Horgg" by Stan Winston](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/175810/31178).

Stan Winston Creatures being the SWC, Inc. on the print. [More info is available on ToyMania](http://www.toymania.com/columns/spotlight/swhorgg.shtml) for Horgg the Destroyer.